# SQL Server login successfully in windows authentication mode but fail in SQL Server authentication mode

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have checked my server is SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.

I am a sa for this server.

I can login successfully in windows authentication. I also create an account but fail to login SQL Server authentication.

I share this sqlserver account and password to others and they can login successfully.
Why does it happen ?
the error log is: 18456, state 1.

---

Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
Line Number: 65536

---

Program Location:

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Comment: Can you share the full text of the error from the SQL Server log? Maybe a login trigger?

Comment: can you post your login parameters thanks

Comment: Not the client side stack trace, the text from the error log file on the SQL Server machine. It should include more details on the cause of the login failure.

Comment: Login failed for user '*****************'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication.  Thanks.  I learn the reason now but I still don't know how I can deal with it

Comment: The message suggests the account specified is a Windows account, qualified with a domain name. For SQL authentication, it must be the login name only.